# NestJS ModuleRef instances

Tags: node.js, nestjs, circular-dependency, requestscope

I'm relatively new to nestJS and ran into a circular dependency with REQUEST Scoped services that got me reading about ModuleRef in nestJS.

I was looking at the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref) where it mentions that resolving the provider by calling it consecutively returns multiple unique instances for this provider.

Now for my use case I only need to call this once so this is not really relevant to me. But I'd like to know when I may have to make these consecutive calls and why we'd need 2 instances of the same provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'd like to know when I may have to make these consecutive calls and why we'd need 2 instances of the same provider.

That's just the thing, generally you wouldn't need to have two instances, **but** the specific documentation you're looking at is regarding `TRANSIENT` scoped providers, which are **different** at every point the are injected, that is, each instance *should* be unique, which is exactly what the documentation is showing here. It then goes to show that **if** you need the same instance, you should use a constant for the `contextId` passed to `ModuleRef#resovle` to ensure that you get the same instance that your resolved earlier